# python-virtualenv : Can't run bash script properly

Tags: python, bash, virtualenv

I am have downloaded the [OCROpus Reader](https://github.com/tmbdev/ocropy) and have installed it in a virtualenv in my Ubuntu machine using -:

```
$ virtualenv ocropus_venv/
$ source ocropus_venv/bin/activate
$ pip install -r requirements_1.txt
# tables has some dependencies which must be installed first:
$ pip install -r requirements_2.txt
$ wget -nd http://www.tmbdev.net/en-default.pyrnn.gz
$ mv en-default.pyrnn.gz models/
```

Now when I following command-:

```
$ ./run-test
```

I get the error-:

```
./run-test: line 4: ocropus-nlbin: command not found
```

Is this a problem because I have installed OCROpus in a virtual environment ? Is the shell script unable to find the PATH to installed packages ?

Need some help.

The content of run-test.sh is-:

```
#!/bin/bash -e

rm -rf temp 
ocropus-nlbin tests/testpage.png -o temp
ocropus-gpageseg 'temp/????.bin.png'
ocropus-rpred -n 'temp/????/??????.bin.png'
ocropus-hocr 'temp/????.bin.png' -o temp.html
ocropus-visualize-results temp
ocropus-gtedit html temp/????/??????.bin.png -o temp-correction.html

echo "to see recognition results, type: firefox temp.html"
echo "to see correction page, type: firefox temp-correction.html"
echo "to see details on the recognition process, type: firefox temp/index.html"
```

Comment: Can you show the content of `run-test` ?

Comment: @AvihooMamka Appended the content of run-test.sh

Comment: If you installed `OCROpus` using `pip` under virtualenv, you need one of the two: 1. export PATH in your script to point the executables you want. 2. give a full path to the executables. e.g: /path/to/virtualenv/bin/ocropus-nlbin ...

Comment: Have you run
`python setup.py install` from within the virtual env.
The documentation misses that step when running in a virtual env.

Comment: @JaseRieger It worked. Thanks. Make your comment into an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to run `python setup.py install` from within the virtual env.

The documentation misses that step when running in a virtual env.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I updated the documentation in ocropy now accordingly (PR #196).